# Proving vectors using axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

(a) Prove that the vector $−u$ whose existence
is asserted by $(V A4)$ is uniquely determined. In other words, show that if $v ∈ V$ satisfies $u + v = 0$, then
it must be the case that $v = −u$

(b) Assume the result proven in (a). Give an argument to
show that $−(−u) = u$.

(c) Assume  the result proven in (a), and the fact proven that $0 · u = 0$. Give an argument to show that $(−1) · u = −u$.

How do I do this? I dont know how to write it out? Is there somewhere I can access that covers this?
 Thank you for anyone that responds im really confused

Comment: What's $(VA4)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) You know $0$ is your neutral element which is unique (because $VA4$, V vectorspace I think) and $u + (-u)= 0$ ; therefore let's assume there's another inverse element $v$ with $0 = u+v$

then with associativity $v=v+(u+u^{-1})= (v+u)+u^{-1}= u^{-1}$

answer for more info^^

Comment: (b) without using (a)directly, just associativity: set $v:=-u$ then $$u= u +(v +(-v))= (u+v) +(-v)= 0 +(-v)= -v$$ therefore $u=-v=-(-u)$

Comment: (c) we need  $1\cdot u = u$ first, $1$ is neutral element of multiplication so this is fulfilled. Further use assume and distributivity: $$0= 0 \cdot u= (1+(-1))\cdot u= 1 \cdot u + (-1) \cdot u= u+ (-1)u$$ and (a) gives us $-u=(-1)u$